# npm install fail (wrong path)

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7

I have a weird problem re-installing node modules in a project of mine.
I am running windows 7 64bit.

I have correctly installed node.js globally.
When typing `node -v` in CMD: `v8.9.4` But when I am trying to use `npm i` (or `npm -v`) in a project of mine I get:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

As you can see path is wrong. It should be `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js`

In My path variables I have:

User variables:

```
NODE_PATH
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
PATH
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm
System Variables ( at the end of others):
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: are you checked your `environmental variables path` ?

Comment: I stated My environmental variables in the question

Comment: I have similar problem but did not find a fix yet, if I do I'll get back here